# I need collapsible div to be opened by default

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im using w3school collapsible, and I need to make it opened by default, what are my options and how can I do it?

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<button class="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Any help will mean a lot. I tried adding `display: block` to content but it didnt helped.

Comment: you want to open all of them by default , even if they are 100 ?

Comment: Yes mate I want them to be opened by default when I enter website, then I can close it if I want it. Is it possible?

Comment: What's the link to the w3schools page? Do you have do it through JavaScript? If not it's probably easier do it from html/css.

Comment: Its: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapsible.asp , Example 3, and no I can do it through css, whatever will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```js
const coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;
//const ClickEvt = new Event('click'); // prepare click event object

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) 
{
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function ()
  {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
  //coll[i].dispatchEvent(ClickEvt); // first click event (new line to add)
  coll[i].click(); 
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
      background-color: #777;
      color: white;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 18px;
      width: 100%;
      border: none;
      text-align: left;
      outline: none;
      font-size: 15px;
    }

    .active,
    .collapsible:hover {
      background-color: #555;
    }

    .content {
      padding: 0 18px;
      max-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
```

```html
<button class="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
      magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <button class="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
      magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <button class="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
      magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat.</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: A little explanation might be helpful. What was the problem and how did you solve it?

Comment: It is very simple, I just add a event click for each one, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent

Comment: So you're simulating a click on each element upon load?

Comment: yes, just after the addEventListener was made. the line has comment

Answer (score 0):

Just change content to this:

```
.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

What was happening before was you were checking the click on the button and showing the content. Now it will show the content by default.

Comment: Its not working, you can try it, I said in the post that I tried that